# How to create snow particle physics?

Tags: physics, particles

Image 1:

[image: Snow falling sim]

Image 2:

[image: Kicking Snow Particles]

Any help or thoughts would be awesome!

Comment: You could probably somewhat simulate it with soft bodies and particle systems, however, the Disney snow simulator is much more advanced than a simple particle system.

Comment: You could also try [this addon](http://www.blendernation.com/2013/11/26/molecular-addon-snow-ball-test/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest thing blender has to your example is a great add on called molecular.
You can watch the demos on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYmaeB6qDtM&feature=share&list=UUOYI8zzas03JA9-Bc_NfbBQ&index=2) to get a feel for what this add on can do.

[molecular download](http://pyroevil.com/molecular-script-download/)

The documentation for molecular is on the same site.