# "Chocolate truffles" in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, objects, workflow, rigid-body-simulation

I'd like to create a chocolate truffle (using Cycles), like in these images:

[image]
[image]

And I'd like to figure out how to have some of the cocoa powder fall off when this 'truffle' falls onto a plane.

Sorry for the lack of Blender files or for more detailed explanation, but I was just baffled trying to figure this out on my own.

Comment: Well, I have tried using particle physics, but the particles (although they seem to be the only option) were a bit difficult to style like cocoa powder... then I tried smoke physics, but that went very weird.

Comment: It seems almost a question of how one could render particles like dust/cocoa powder.

Comment: related?: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6442/how-to-create-snow-particle-physics and http://pyroevil.com/molecular-script-docs/

Comment: Increase the roughness on the diffuse shader.